# Material Design Lite responsive CSS not working on a Mobile/Tablets or in the Chrome DevTools emulator

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, material-design-lite

When experimenting with the responsive features of Google's [Material Design Lite](http://getmdl.io), this code hides messages as expected when resizing the browser window, but when I look at my page in Chrome DevTools device emulator or on an actual device, it only shows the "Desktop" version. How do I fix my HTML?

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
       <div class="mdl-cell--hide-phone mdl-cell--hide-tablet">
          You are on a desktop
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-cell--hide-desktop mdl-cell--hide-tablet">
          You are on a phone
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-cell--hide-desktop mdl-cell--hide-phone">
          You are on a tablet
       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix MDL not scaling for different devices, add this line inside your HTML's `<head>` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```